# Extracting Rest API from WebApp in Laravel

Tags: api, laravel

I built a web app in Laravel 5.2, and now, I would like to use Angular or Vue, so I am separating an API from my controllers.

Thing is actually, in my controllers, I use a lot :

```
Auth::user() to refer to the logged user.
```

What is the best way to deal with it???

Answer (score 0):

Read books about API design. If the existing app isn't designed to be a RESTful API in the first place then you're in for a lot of learning. Laracasts has a great series called Incremental APIs.

Laracasts.com

[Build APIs You Won't Hate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0692232699)

OK, I'm expanding my answer, despite this is not a great question, it is probably too broad. You need to look into Oauth 2.0 authentication for your API, you can still use a username and password, but OAuth 2.0 tokens over SSL is probably the best simple way to provide authentication for your API. If it is only used internally, or is read only then you may not really require authentication for the API at all. There's not enough information about your use case to even make a guess about that. Good luck!

Comment: yep, I just seen it!

Comment: There's a lot about RESTful APIs that isn't in there, but it is a start. It really depends how much REST you can take. 
The "Build APIs You Won't Hate" book is a really good next step if you want to learn some good and differing approaches, including the best-in-class approaches to versioning and maintaining HATEOAS.